# Marketing Cloud SQL Query Count Boolean not working

Tags: sql, boolean, salesforce-marketing-cloud

i've got a boolean field within our customer database. i want to query it in query studio.

I want to count in the end how many customers got the new T&Cs and how many not by product.

for that i wrote...

```
, COUNT(CASE WHEN X_customer = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS X_Customer_Count
, COUNT(CASE WHEN Y_customer = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Y_Customer_Count
```

or

```
 , COUNT(CASE WHEN X_customer = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS X_Customer_Count
, COUNT(CASE WHEN Y_customer = 'False' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Y_Customer_Count
```

X customer = has signed T&C New

Y customer = has signed T&C Old

Both works and give me some result. I dont see an error. BUT the result within both columns is exactly the same. Why? It should only count if its either true or false.

Help? :)

Answer (score 0):

COUNT will just count any non-null value, so it will count those values whether they are 1 or 0. Try using SUM instead